# how to write aggregater functions in spring-hibernate module?

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, spring-roo

I have a requirement like I have to find the max id from the table by passing two parameters to find the particular row, and I have set one value of the column in that row. Here by passing the mac address and user id.

```
query=session.createQuery("updateLoginStatusDAO set loginStatus=:loginStatus, logoutDate=: logoutDate where macAddress=:macAddress and LoginId=:LoginId");
                query.setInteger("loginStatus", status).setString("logoutDate",logoutDate).setString("macAddress", macAddress).setString("LoginId", userId);
                updateStatus=   query.executeUpdate();
```